# Method called before constructor in overridden JTable

Tags: java

I have one class extending  JScrollPane, that's creating an object of another class that extends JTable. Basically it looks like this:

```
class CustomScrollPane{
   private CustomTable table

   public CustomScrollPane(..){
   table = new CustomTable(this);
   ..
   }
   public void scrollToBottom(){
      ...
   }
}
```

In the CustomTable class I override tableChanged:

```
public class CustomTable extends JTable{

private CustomScrollPane scrollPane;

public CustomTable(CustomScrollPane scrollPane){
    super();
    this.scrollPane = scrollPane;
}

@Override
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    super.tableChanged(e);
    scrollPane.scrollToBottom();
}
```

When I run this I get a NullPointerException on scrollPane in tableChanged(), how is that possible? How can scrollPane be null when it was set in the constructor? Running it in the debugger shows that tableChanged() is called before the constructor. Adding the condition

```
     if (scrollPane != null)
```

actually fixes the problem, because later on the constructor is called. Also, defining the JTable as its constructed, like:

```
        table = new JTable(){
        @Override
        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
            final Component c = super.prepareRenderer(new CustomTableCellRenderer(), row, column);
            if (c instanceof JComponent){
                ((JComponent) c).setOpaque(true);
            }
            return c;
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            int scrolling = scrollPane.getViewport().getViewPosition().y;
            super.paint(g);
            g.drawImage(image.getImage(), -30, -50 + scrolling, null, null);
        }

        @Override
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
            super.tableChanged(e);
            scrollPane.scrollToBottom();
        }
    };
```

directly in the CustomScrollPane constructor also works. Why can't a break it out into a seperate class?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have another constructor either in CustomScrollPane or CustomTable that is actually getting called ? Run the debugger again and see which constructor in CustomTable is being called from which constructor in CustomScrollPane.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. It appears to call some other constructor from JPanel, which I find kind of strange since that constructor, whatever it is, can't possibly have the same arguments as mine (objects of my own classes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `JTable` constructor invokes method `tableChanged(...)` - which means it is invoked before you're able to initialize the `scrollPane` instance variable.

First, I suggest you take a look at some puzzlers in the book [Java Puzzlers](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/contents.html) - specifically puzzle 51: What's the Point and maybe puzzle 53: Do Your Thing. They should help you understand what's going on. Basically, the first line of your `CustomTable` constructor invokes the `JTable` constructor (via `super()`). The `JTable` constructor is trying to invoke `tableChanged` - which has been overriden. The overriden `tableChanged` tries to manipulate `scrollPane`... but all this is happening on line 1 of your constructor (`super()`) - *before* the line `this.scrollPane = scrollPane` has executed, so `scrollPane` is still null.

Next, I suggest using the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Here you have two objects - your scroll pane and the custom table - and one needs to be notified when the other is changed. That is textbook observer pattern. Here's the rough idea:

## File `CustomTable.java`

```
public class CustomTable extends JTable {

    // No more scroll pane; only observers
    private List<ChangeListener> listeners = [];

    // no more scroll pagne
    public CustomTable(){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
        super.tableChanged(e);
        this.fireChangeEvent();
    }

    /* new methods */

    public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
        // ...
    }

    private void fireChangeEvent() {
        for(String l : listeners ){
            l.onChange();
        }
    }
}
```

## File `CustomScrollPane.java`

```
class CustomScrollPane implements ChangeListener{
   private CustomTable table

   public CustomScrollPane(/*...*/){
       table = new CustomTable();
       table.addChangeListener(this);
       //...
   }

   public void scrollToBottom(){
      //...
   }

   /* new methods */

  @Override
  public void onChange() {
      scrollToBottom();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the constructor info, the link and the pattern suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

This is classical very bad pattern of having partially-initialized instances escaping the scope of the constructor.

I guess that CustomScrollPane fires some events to table CustomTable when you invoke new CustomTable(this);

and since the scrollPane is not yet initialized - then you're getting NPE.

Just never let things to escape the constructor - and you're safe.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're suggesting. Do you think I should remove
    table = new CustomTable(this);
from the constructor and instead add a setTable() method?

Comment: pls take a look at the next answer here, it describes my point with great details